# Pass-through geometry shader

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, shader, geometry-shader

I just started with OpenGL in conjunction with Qt. I try to use a geometry shader to change the width of lines, but even a simple pass-through geometry shader results in an empty screen.

Here is (an excerpt of) my code:

```
line_shader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/shaders/lines.v.glsl");
line_shader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/shaders/lines.f.glsl");
line_shader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Geometry, ":/shaders/lines.g.glsl");
line_shader.setGeometryInputType(GL_LINES);
line_shader.setGeometryOutputType(GL_LINES);
line_shader.setGeometryOutputVertexCount(100);
line_shader.link();
line_shader.bind();


const float data[] = {
0, 0, 0, 3,    0.8, 0, 0, 0.5,      1, 0, 0, 3,    0.8, 0, 0, 0.5,
0, 0, 0, 3,    0, 0.8, 0, 0.5,      0, 1, 0, 3,    0, 0.8, 0, 0.5,
0, 0, 0, 3,    0, 0, 0.8, 0.5,      0, 0, 1, 3,    0, 0, 0.8, 0.5,
};
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 


glUseProgram(line_shader.programId());

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

GLint a_vertex = line_shader.attributeLocation("a_vertex");
GLint a_color = line_shader.attributeLocation("a_color");
line_shader.enableAttributeArray(a_vertex);
line_shader.enableAttributeArray(a_color);

glVertexAttribPointer(a_vertex, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(a_color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(4 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_vertex;
attribute vec4 a_color;
uniform mat4 u_pmv_matrix;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = u_pmv_matrix * vec4(a_vertex.x, a_vertex.y, a_vertex.z, 1);
}
```

Geometry shader:

```
void main() {
  for (int i=0; i<gl_VerticesIn; ++i) {
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[i];
    EmitVertex();
  }
  EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 v_color;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

If I remove `line_shader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Geometry, ":/shaders/lines.g.glsl");` from the code, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I use OS X 10.9, Qt 5.2.1.

Comment: you don't pass the color of the emitted vertices

Comment: Thanks, but I know. I intentionally deactivated it and set the color manually in the fragment shader.

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: When using QGLWidget the compilation of the shaders failed when setting the version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are geometry shaders supported by an extension that is not being loaded/resolved on your platform?  I believe they're optional, but Qt tries to load them ([source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/staging/commit/fe849f5)).

Perhaps they're named something different in your implementation.  If you have to manually resolve them [this KDAB article](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) may help.  There's code there to list the extensions Qt knows about:

```
// Query extensions
QList extensions = m_context->extensions().toList();
std::sort( extensions );
qDebug() << "Supported extensions (" << extensions.count() << ")";
foreach ( const QByteArray &extension, extensions )
   qDebug() << "    " << extension;
```

It might be that the extension is called something other than what Qt expects.

Also obvious, but I guess you have a shader tool on your platform and have been able to run that shader?  I use MacOSX for most of my development and unfortunately the "OpenGL Shader Builder" tool only supports fragment and vertex shaders.  I'm not sure what tools do support geometry shaders but I guess you've arrived at that shader and verified it somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed on OSX 10.9 with a very new machine. I did what you suggested and it gives me the following: http://pastebin.com/tZUPtEcr, Geometry Shaders are listed there. Sorry, these are my first steps with OpenGL. How would I activate the geometry shader in this case?

Comment: OK, I realize that OpenGL support is a mess in Qt5. They recommend to replace QGL* functions with QOpenGL* counterparts, but they do not provide a QOpenGLWidget class yet.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it lead me in the right direction. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked, and apologies for not monitoring this.

They might not ever provide an explicit GL Widget, as its easy enough to create your own by binding a QWindow and QOpenGLContext like this:  https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/source/d3338a9f7fcac109d7bc7f600d5974ff333782ad:src/threed/viewing/qglview.cpp#L336